# New to ROS humble, getting error when executing 'ros launch'

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, ros-humble

I have ros installed in a VM and so far i did communication and package tutorials without problems. However, when I executed `roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf` for the first time, got the follwing:

```
     'Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module>
        import roslaunch
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
        from .scriptapi import ROSLaunch
    
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in <module>
        import roslaunch.parent
    
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 54, in <module>
        import roslaunch.server
    
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 80, in <module>
        from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
    
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Log' from 'rosgraph_msgs.msg' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/__init__.py)'
```

I don't know how to fix this and don't want to reinstall everything if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Can you please share your environment details as the question is tagged with `ros2` but using `roslaunch`, which was designed for `ros1`?